# VS Code user snippet convert filename camel case to kebab case

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

for like:

MyCustomeComponents -> my-custom-components

I find several other way, but none of camel case to kebab case

other way link: https://gist.github.com/natemoo-re/94cfba2bfb17cbeec0680c05309ea9ee

Comment: do you want to rename a file itself? Or rename a reference to a file's name contained in a file?

Answer (score 1):

I have written this with Selected Text but you can replace it with any `TM_` variable

```json
  "CamelCase to Kebab": {
    "prefix": "camelkebab",
    "body": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(^[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z0-9])([A-Z])/${1:/downcase}${2:+-}${2:/downcase}/g}",
  }
```